# Working on large database using scheduler in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.8

I made a command and registered it in Kernel.php named "offers:update".
This command should do some changes on "offers" table depending on current status of each offer daily at 00:00.
My "offers" table might have above 100,000 rows and i want to do changes in the the most optimized way.

I've read the documentation (v 5.8) and found chunk() method.

Is it enough or there is better idea?

Comment: Yup, chunk is perfect.

Comment: `chunk()` can still be pretty inefficient, as it still has to fetch 100000 rows before it can split it into chunks. I'd suggest using DB limit/offset if possible. But, if performance/execution time isn't a huge issue, such as in the case of a command-line command, `chunk()` is ok.

Comment: @TimLewis That's false. `chunk` uses limit/offset. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#chunking-results See the source at https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php#L18 and the `forPage` function it uses at https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1940.

Comment: @ceejayoz Oh interesting; I didn't realize that `Eloquent` has a `chunk()` function on it; I thought you had to convert it to a `Collection` first. That's good to know. Then yes, if `chunk()` uses limit/offset behind the scenes, it is perfect.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you very much man ♥

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have faced the same problem 2 months ago but with 1 000 000 in my db table and I confirm that chunk() is the best solution at this moment